# Using the keyword "new" in a return statement

Tags: java

I have never seen the keyword "new" used in a return statement and my understanding of new is that it creates a new object. And "new" used in this context `Practice permutation = new Practice();` is that it creates a new object called `permutation`. And `permutation` is a reference to some memory address. So maybe, `return new String(content)` is return a memory address? So my question is, what does `new` used in this context actually mean? I apologize for my noob question...

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Practice {
    public String sort(String s) {
        char[] content = s.toCharArray(); 
        Arrays.sort(content);
        return new String(content);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Practice permutation = new Practice(); 
        System.out.println(permutation.sort("hello"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Apply same permutation theory you explained to class defined right after new.

Comment: `new` creates an object. You're returning a new object. `return new String(content)` will return a String object constructed with `content` as the parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return new String(content);` means it creates a new string object with the content you have passed. It's similar to

```
String str = new String(content)
return str;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!

Answer (score 3):

When using the keyword *new* you shouldn't associate it with any assignment operator. What the *new* keyword does, in laymans terms, is it creates a reference to a new instance of the specified class and returns it. So when you put the statement

```
new Object();
```

That statement is completely valid and it is returning a new reference to an Object class. The only thing is that the reference doesn't get set to anything because there is no operator performing on it. So when you have

```
Object myObj = new Object();
```

The reference comes from the *new Object()* statement and the equals operator sets it equal to the myObj variable. So now, if you understand that, when you have

```
return new Object();
```

The reference comes from the *new Object()* statement again and the *return* keyword takes that reference and returns it out of the method that you're in.

Answer (score 2):

Your theory is correct, but your understanding of variables is a little off (in a very common way...) An object never has a name; it exists independently of any variables referring to it<sup>1</sup>. `Practice permutation = new Practice();` does three things:

- It creates a new `Practice` object
- It creates a new variable that may refer to a `Practice` object
- It makes the variable actually refer to the new object

Note that `permutation` is not the name of the object; it is the name of the variable, and the variable *refers* to the object. You can create several variables that refer to the same object, and you can create an object that is not referred to by anything - and the latter is what happens in `return new`.

<sup>1</sup>Whether there are any references to an object actually *does* have an effect, as an unreferenced object may be garbage collected - but that is a more advanced topic.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I'm just going to try to explain it to you to ensure that I understand it. So Practice is a class and permutation is a variable that holds the reference (or the memory address?) to a Practice object. And this practice object is stored in the heap somewhere, along with practice object's member variables and methods? Is this right? Kind of?

Comment: @Jae: Yes, except that an object only contains the values of its member variables. The code for the methods only needs to be stored once, so that is stored in the class instead. When you call e.g. `permutation.sort("foo")`, Java will (behind the scenes) send the object reference in `permutation` as a parameter to the `sort` method so that the method knows which object to operate on. Inside a method, you can use `this` to get hold of that reference.

Comment: I see... Thank you for your explanation, it's super clear. One more question, where is the class stored then? Is it stored in the stack?

Comment: @Jae: The class metadata itself is stored in the [_Permanent Generation_](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation) (PermGen), which is a separate memory area within the Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset can you explore your this line? `You can create several variables that refer to the same object` how We can do that? any example please?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq: `ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(); ArrayList<Integer> b = a;` - now, `a` and `b` refer to the same `ArrayList` object, and if you make any change to the list through either `a` or `b`, the change will be visible through the other variable: `a.add(42); System.out.println(b.get(0));`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
return new String(content);
```

Is (logically) identical to this:

```
String result = new String(content);
return result;
```

It just skips the step of storing the value in a variable and returns it directly.  There's nothing different happening, a new object is being instantiated and an object is being returned.

Comment: Haha. Thank you. I'm so noob.

Comment: So, when I do `String result = new String(content);`, I am somehow putting a char array into a String? Is some sort of casting happening here? Sorry for the noob question again...

Comment: @Jae: One of the constructors for `String` accepts a `char[]`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html  All you're doing is instantiating a new `String` object using one of its constructors.

Answer (score 1):

```
return new String(content);
```

does 3 things:

1) In creates `String` object somewhere in memory

2) In creates pointer (or reference) to it in this stack of you current thread

3) It returns this reference to the caller.

The same as

```
s = new String(content);
return s;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!